# CLOSED connection issues with JPA transation manager

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am consistently running into JPA closed connection issues. I am using spring 3.0.5 with hibernate 3.0. I am using JPA transaction manager to manage my services and using REQUIRED propagation.

Here is my scenario.

```
Table A
id    
desc (LAZY)

Table B
a_id

a_id in Table B refers to id of Table A.
```

I want to load entity A given an entity B.

```
Here is what I am doing (roughly) inside the controller:
List<B> list = serviceB.find() ;

for each element - itemB in above list : itemA = serviceA.find(itemB.a_id);
convert itemA to UI bean and set it in model.
```

I am assuming that each of the find() methods in my service will be executed inside a transaction, by virtue of a REQUIRED propagation. However, for the second find() it throws exception , and that too intermittently. Sometimes it says CLOSED connection, and at other times it says 'Transaction not active', and strangely some other times it does work as expected ! Driving me crazy..

Help appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with multiple threads accessing same service methods. When I change my UI pages to make serial access instead of parallel (using ajax), this does not occur. Will have to make entity manager work with multi threaded scenario.